# Problems with importing Tensoflow in Jupyter. DLL load failed. Specific module failed to load

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, jupyter

I opened up a Jupyter notebook and tried importing tensorflow as tf and got the following error message

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

And here's the message I received

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-622d614f2d45> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 
      3 #from tensorflow.keras import layers
      4 #from tensorflow.keras import losses
      5 #from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Name\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I tried installing it with the following commands

```
# install pip in the virtual environment
  conda install pip
# install Tensorflow CPU version
  pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow # for python 3.*
# install Keras (Note: please install TensorFlow first)
  pip install Keras
```

But I'm still getting the same error message. I'm using windows 10 if that helps.

Oh I also checked in my command line to see if it was working in python by doing

```
python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

But I still got the same error message

Comment: Are you using Tf2.1? If so, check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749) thread for solutions.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I think I'm using 2.4.1 The thread was helpful though because I saw someone download the x86 and x64 bit versions of visual c++ and that solved it for them.  It worked for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem should be fixed by installing the 
[`Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Comment: So I downloaded x86 and restarted my computer but I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do now.  Because I tried importing tensorflow as tf from python and it still gave the same error message

Comment: @iYOA Did you run the exe? Are you running a 64 bit or 32 bit system? Also, which tensorflow version are you using? Are you using with or without gpu? This can help me narrow down, the possible solutions.

Comment: Okay so I downloaded the 64x version as well and I think it seems to be working.  It was just the cpu version, so I think it'll complain some more about the gpu cuda modules not being installed but I think this should be fine for the imdb dataset.